# Agile PLM API create relationship between items: Invalid Parameter

Tags: oracle, scala, agile, oracle-agile-plm

I'm developing an scala application using Agile PLM API.
Everything works so far, adding attachments, adding BOM items, creating items and so on.

But when creating Relationships in the Relationship Table, I always get this error:

```
com.agile.api.APIException: Invalid parameter.
  at com.agile.api.pc.Session.createError(Session.java:2039)
  at com.agile.api.pc.APIObject.createError(APIObject.java:76)
  at com.agile.api.pc.TableRelationships.convertCreateParamMapToVOCells(TableRelationships.java:92)
  at com.agile.api.pc.TablePC.doCreateServerRowWithParam(TablePC.java:58)
  at com.agile.api.pc.Table.createTableRow(Table.java:267)
  at com.agile.api.pc.Table.createRow(Table.java:231)
```

The Agile API requires a hashmap with attributes and values as parameter to create the relationship. So this is my code:

```
val cells: java.utils.Map[_, _] = Map(
    Attrs.Items.Relationships.CriteriaMet -> null,
    Attrs.Items.Relationships.TypeImage -> 666, // id of item type as Integer
    Attrs.Items.Relationships.Name -> "foo", // name as String
    Attrs.Items.Relationships.Description -> "bar", // the description as String
    Attrs.Items.Relationships.CurrentStatus -> "Production", // lifecyclephase 'Production' as a String
    Attrs.Items.Relationships.Rule -> null,
    Attrs.Items.Relationships.Type -> 600 // id of item type as Integer
) 

relationshipTable.createRow(cells)
```

The relationshipTable instance is of type ITable and this kind of Map is working for adding BOM items and attachments, so I think this is not the issue here.

I simply queried the cells of existing relationships manually and compared their key with my constants used in this map and they are the same. I really don't know what the invalid parameter is. Is there an attribute missing? Is the type of an parameter wrong? There is no indication what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer was quite simple, despite it works different than for the BOM and it is not documented.

The solution is simply passing the iitem you want to add as a relationship:
relationshipTable.createRow(iitem)